# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str")

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to automatically create vlan in our device but my script throws this error:

> ```
> tn.write(cmd + "\n")   
> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple.
> ```

```
vlannumbers = int(input("Enter the number for vlans :"))
for i in range(2,vlannumbers):
    cmd = (("/cfg/l2/vlan "), i)

    tn.write(cmd + "\n")
    cmd1 = "apply"
    tn.write(cmd1 + "\n")
    print "ok"
    tn.close()
```

Comment: the code is in correct format

Comment: What is this? `cmd = (("/cfg/l2/vlan "), i)` if `i=0`, then what should it show?

Comment: if i = 0 it should not do anything in my device vlan starts from 1 and i have give range from 2

Comment: Okay, what if `i = 2`?, what should `cmd` be?

Comment: for eg if i = 2 cmd should be like this /cfg/l2/vlan 2

Comment: if i have value i = 3 then i need /cfg/l2/vlan 3 need to be printed here but its not happening

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` is holding tuple value in your code (not string). For example:

```
>>> cmd = (("/cfg/l2/vlan "), 2)
>>> type(cmd)
<type 'tuple'>   # <--- it's tuple
```

Since you want to initialize it as string, you should be doing:

```
cmd = "/cfg/l2/vlan {}".format(i)
```

Comment: if i = 4 then cmd must be /cfg/l2/vlan 4 then apply it this is not happening.

Comment: It will work as far as the value of `i` (from the `for` loop) is 4. Try to add `print(i)` within your loop and debug

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is a join between objects of type `string`.

You may try this:

```
vlannumbers = int(input("Enter the number for vlans :"))
cmd_base = "/cdg/l2/vlan"
for i in range(2,vlannumbers):
    # cmd_base is not affected, 
    # since concatenated string value is stored in `cmd`
    cmd = cmd_base + "%d"%i 
    tn.write(cmd + "\n")
    cmd1 = "apply"
    tn.write(cmd1 + "\n")
    print "ok"
    tn.close()
```